# Where might be the issue if the image is not rendered only in InternetExplorer , when the application is deployed in new server?

Tags: image, internet-explorer

Recently we deployed our java web application in tomcat 8.5.32. In the pages, some jpg images are not displayed in IE alone (no issue with other browsers). We could see some jpg images are rendered in IE but not all. But in legacy server, we don't see any such issue. Where/What could be the problem?

I used the developer tool in the IE, to see if the image is loaded or not. I could see the image in the network tab.

I tried the url to image in the browser location bar, still i face the same issue.

I need all jpg images rendered in the IE browser.

Comment: What's your IE browser version? Try to clear the browser cache and reload the page. Also, you could test your application on another machine and check whether it works well. Besides, I suggest you could also try to refer to the solution in [this thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2108938.aspx?Image+displaying+on+Chrome+and+Firefox+but+not+IE+11) and [this issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/internet-explorer-11-not-displaying-picture-images/b947e0fe-e726-4f9f-bbd6-4857be94ff60), if still not working, reset the browser setting or reinstall the browser.

Comment: Thanks Zhi. i tried the application in other machine as well. I tried the attached thread link. No luck. wondering what could the issue with the IE alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last the header "**X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff**" is the reason for this. The images served from my portal are saved as jpeg. But actually, they are bmp files. Since original type(BMP) is different from the type in the response header("image/jpeg"), IE browser is unable to decode it and failed to render the image.